# Executing shell script parallelly and in background skips some operation

Tags: shell, pipe, background-process, lock

```
del_client.sh --delete client1 &
del_client.sh --delete client2 &
del_client.sh --delete client3 &
del_client.sh --delete client4 &
```

When I executed the commands above in the background, `client1` was not deleted.

```
del_client.sh
```

code which is called during the operation above:

```
del_client_entry()[

cat $FILE |grep -v ^"${entry}\." | grep -v ^"# ${entry} VT" > $FILE.del
        cp -p $FILE.del $FILE
}
```

Comment: I don't know how `$FILE` is determined inside the script but it sounds like all 4 invocations of the script might be manipulating the same file at the same time. Since you do not serialize access to the file with a lock, that would explain your result since you would then be facing a race condition.

Comment: I agree. That's why i am trying to implement locking mechanism.

Comment: You don't show any code that would delete a file, why do you expect one to be deleted? How is `$FILE` set? How is `$entry` set? Ho can we know where the error is if you don't show us your script? Please [edit] your question and give us more information.

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't say where `$FILE` gets its value from, but it sounds like every invocation of the script is actually manipulating the same `$FILE`.

If that's true, then your 4 invocations are racing with each other and the failure you see is expected. Because you carry out a non-atomic read+modify+replace operation on this file and you don't use mutual exclusion to make sure only one process is in its critical section at a time, one of the invocations of the file can easily clobber another's modifications.

You should run `del_client_entry` under a lock. For example:

```
(
    flock 9
    del_client_entry <parameters>
) 9>/my/lock/file
```

Comment: Initially i was giving same file  name, in which i was making changes in /my/lock/file ,so it was not working. Later i gave 9>/tmp/lck, then it worked.            Thanks a lot Celada :)